# PHP Iterating Through Associative Array

Tags: php, associative-array

So I have the following, working code:

```
$arrayitertest=Array("Fruit"=>Array("Pear","Peach","Apple","Banana"),"Cars"=>Array("My budget","other cars."));

foreach ($arrayitertest as $key=>$value)
foreach($arrayitertest[$key] as $result) echo $key.":". $result."|";
```

But when I change `foreach ($arrayitertest as $key => $value)` to `foreach ($arrayitertest as $key)` it throws a fatal error (despite the fact I never use the $key variable.)

The Error is:Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Could someone be so kind as to tell me why that happens ?

**Edit:** Wow, thanks for all the answers.... I will give the accept to the most specific one as of this moment though.

Comment: Can you post the error? Also in the first foreach you have $key/$value vars backwards.

Comment: You have a bracket that isn't closed after the first foreach.

Comment: Brackets are also missing entirely from the second foreach.

Comment: Your foreach is backwards.  It's $kay => $value

Comment: What @shapeshifter said.  Your commenting out the closing bracket.  Change `//echo $value."|".$key1."\n";` to `/*echo $value."|".$key1."\n";*/` to correctly comment out the code within the foreach.

Comment: The correct foreach format is: `foreach($array as $key => $value) { /*looped code goes here*/ }`

Comment: Thanks guys fixed all that stuff lol ... but the essence of the question remains the same.

Comment: and  `as $result=>$v`

Comment: @user1833028 If you remove the `$value` from the first `foreach`, `$key` becomes the value and `$arrayitertest[$key]` becomes `"pear"` which is an invalid argument for the second `foreach`, see my answer.

Comment: Wow thanks guys, almost wish I could accept more than one answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as your error is concerned: If you remove the `$value` from the first `foreach`, `$key` becomes the value and `$arrayitertest[$key]` becomes `"pear"` which is an invalid argument for the second `foreach`.

Your program would halt on:

```
// this is not going to work
foreach ("pear" as $result)
```

If you don't need the key of the first `foreach` you can just change it to:

```
foreach ($arrayitertest as $value)
{
   foreach($value as $result)
   {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are misunderstanding the order of key and values. Where you say `$value => $key` it's technically `$key => $value`.

The way to parse your array is this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($array[$key] as $v) {
        // $v = Pear (1st iteration), Peach (2nd), Apple (3rd) ... (for key = Fruit) 
        // $v = My Budget (1st iteration), other cars. (2nd) (for key = Cars)
        // notice that $key is also accessible here
    }
}
```

Obviously if you don't need the `$key` either you can simply:

```
foreach ($array as $a)
    foreach ($a as $v)
        // use $v here
```

Answer (score 0):

Coding $value => $key, puts Fruit, Car, ... into $value.

Coding just $value puts the arrays such as Array("Pear","Peach","Apple","Banana") into $value and that is not a valid index for an array.